# Free API/library that allows processing/Iterating/querying Scientific articles (i.e. Google Scholar)?

Tags: web-scraping, google-scholar

I'm trying to find a feasible way to iterate over all Scientific Papers on Google Scholar (or any other Scientific library). I do not need the paper content, only Title, Author, Citations & Abstract.

I'm looking for some type of libraries/api's that allow me to iterate and process these papers, as well as something with high querying capabilities.

The only one I found so far is [scholarly](https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/). It seems pretty good for querying, however, I do not see any option for iterating through everything.

Is there any other web scraping tool that allows me to do that?

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your specific purpose, it is a bit difficult to give a good response.

But nevertheless, the go-to-place for scientific metadata (e.g. title, authors, citations) would be [CrossRef's API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc). It is free to use.

While I do not know how you determine your sample, you could, for instance, take the ISSN of a journal to fetch metadata about the journal's papers ([example here](https://api.crossref.org/journals/1531-5088)), or you can use a publication's DOI to obtain metadata about that specific paper ([example here](https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1177/1369148118786043)).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all articles indexed by [Crossref](https://www.crossref.org/) using their API's [`/works`](https://api.crossref.org/swagger-ui/index.html#/Works/get_works) endpoint.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?cursor=*
```

This returns a JSON object with a `message` field whose `items` array contains the first "page" of 20 "works" from the Crossref index.

```json
{
  "status": "ok",
  "message-type": "work-list",
  "message": {
    "next-cursor":"DnF1ZXJ5==",
    "total-results": 154654040,
    "items": [
      {
        "DOI": "10.1111/jan.13843",
        "type": "journal-article",
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

You can fetch the next page of results by setting the `cursor` query parameter to the `next-cursor` value from the JSON response's `message` object. Make sure to URL-encode the cursor value to properly escape the `==` suffix.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?cursor=DnF1ZXJ5%3D%3D
```

Note that this endpoint by default returns all types of works indexed by Crossref. If you want to iterate over only journal articles, you'd have to specify the work's `type` in the `filter` query parameter.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?filter=type:journal-article&cursor=*
```

The types of "work" you can filter for in the Crossref index are `book-section`, `monograph`, `report-component`, `report`, `peer-review`, `book-track`, `journal-article`, `book-part`, `other`, `book`, `journal-volume`, `book-set`, `reference-entry`, `proceedings-article`, `journal`, `component`, `book-chapter`, `proceedings-series`, `report-series`, `proceedings`, `database`, `standard`, `reference-book`, `posted-content`, `journal-issue`, `dissertation`, `grant`, `dataset`, `book-series`, and `edited-book`.

You probably want to filter for `journal-article`s and `proceeding-article`, so you'd specify them both in the `filter` parameter in a comma-separated list.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?filter=type:proceedings-article,type:journal-article&cursor=*
```

That will give you all information about 20 journal articles or conference proceedings articles from the Crossref index. You can request more or less works at a time by specifying the `rows` query parameter. The following example shows a request for 50 works at a time.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?rows=50&cursor=*
```

The Crossref API by default provides all metadata about each work it returns. This can add up to a large amount of data for large `row` sizes, so you might want to use the `select` query parameter to specify exactly which metadata fields you want to retrieve for each work. The following example requests the `DOI`, `type`, and `title` fields. You can see the full list of fields in the "Elements" section of the [Crossref API documentation on `/works`](https://api.crossref.org/swagger-ui/index.html#/Works/get_works).

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?select=DOI,type,title&cursor=*
```

Last, but not least, you're going to want to use [the "polite" service](https://www.crossref.org/documentation/retrieve-metadata/rest-api/tips-for-using-the-crossref-rest-api/#pick-the-right-service-level) by specifying an email address in a `mailto` query parameter.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?mailto=me@example.com&cursor=*
```

Alternatively, you can use the police service by including a `mailto:` URI in the `User-Agent` HTTP header.

```http
GET /works?cursor=* HTTP/1.1
Host: api.crossref.org
User-Agent: (mailto:me@example.com)
```

Putting everything together, here's the final API request for the DOI, type, and title of the first page of 50 journal and conference proceeding articles in the Citeref index, using the polite service.

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?rows=50&select=DOI,type,title&filter=type:proceedings-article,type:journal-article&mailto=me@example.com&cursor=*
```

You can click on the following link to check for yourself that it works, although I've removed the `mailto` parameter because I don't think it'd be very polite to use the "polite" service with an invalid email address.

https://api.crossref.org/works?rows=50&select=DOI,type,title&filter=type:proceedings-article,type:journal-article&cursor=*

I recommend reading through the documentation yourself and playing around with the different endpoints. Their error messages can actually be pretty useful. I actually got that list of "works" types in an error I got after I sent an invalid type.

- [Metadata Retrieval REST API](https://www.crossref.org/documentation/retrieve-metadata/rest-api/): A conceptual overview of the Crossref REST API.
- [Crossref Unified Resource API](https://api.crossref.org/swagger-ui/index.html): Swagger docs detailing the specific REST endpoints.
- [REST API Doc](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc): Older documentation for the deprecated API, but still a useful reference.